# How to use base member initialization on an array?

Tags: c++, initialization

Making a blackjack game and need to know how to initialize an array using base member initialization (i.e. intializing within a constructor using the unary scope resolution operator).

```
//Constructor
Card::Card()
:mRank(static_cast<Rank>(ACE)), mSuit(static_cast<Suit>(SPADES)), mRankText(), mSuitText()
{
}
```

I want to initialize the ragged arrays mRankText and mSuitText to

```
const char * rankText[NUMBER_OF_RANKS] = {"Ace", 
                                          "Deuce", 
                                          "Trey", 
                                          "Four", 
                                          "Five", 
                                          "Six", 
                                          "Seven", 
                                          "Eight", 
                                          "Nine", 
                                          "Ten", 
                                          "Jack", 
                                          "Queen", 
                                          "King"};

const char * suitText[NUMBER_OF_SUITS] = {"Spades", 
                                          "Clubs", 
                                          "Diamonds", 
                                          "Hearts"};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> base member initialization (i.e. intializing within a constructor using the unary scope resolution operator).

It's called a *ctor-initializer* or *mem-initializer-list* (or just a "constructor initializer list") and there's no such thing as "the unary scope resolution operator" that's called a colon!

Prior to C++11 you can't do this, you can only leave the array uninitialized or initialize all members to zero (which is what your code is doing now.)

In C++11 you can use uniform initialization with braces:

```
//Constructor
Card::Card()
: /*...*/, mRankText{ a, b, c }, mSuitText{ d, e, f, g }
{
}
```

That requires explicitly specifying each element, to automate it you need to use a delegating constructor and variadic templates. The following uses the `std::index_sequence` type which will be in C++14, but you can do it today with my [integer_seq.h](https://gitorious.org/redistd/integer_seq/blobs/master/integer_seq.h) implementation:

```
//Constructor
Card::Card()
: Card(std::make_index_sequence<NUMBER_OF_RANKS>(),
       std::make_index_sequence<NUMBER_OF_SUITS>())
{ }

template<size_t... R, size_t... S>
Card::Card(std::index_sequence<R...>, std::index_sequence<S...>)
: /*...*/, mRankText{ rankText[R]... }, mSuitText{ suitText[I]... }
{
}
```